# Changing on Subcategories Images

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am having problem on changing the 2 images (bracket in red border) or it is 1 piece
[image]

I've tried to look into Modules, Changing on Category's thumbnail and it doesn't seems to be work.

This is running on the Prestashop Default-Bootstrap theme.

And Prestashop Version is 1.6.0.9

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue due to I've disabled the *Categories block* module earlier on.

Make sure *Categories block* module is enable by navigate to Modules > Modules > Search for keywords "Categories".

And go to Catalog > Categories > Edit the Category, you should now able to see the thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

It's not category thumb, it is Menu thumb (at least in ps 1.6.4.1)[image: back-end]

You should update it in parent category